# Is there a way of using linked lists to simplify my Monte-Carlo code

Tags: c, linked-list, montecarlo

Hiya, my code currently has three functions each producing a massive array of random numbers.  Im wondering if there is a way of just having one function returning a linked list or multidimensional array to make it a bit neater:

(copied from http://pastebin.com/Y5aE6XKS)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#ifndef RAND_MAX
#define RAND_MAX 2147483648
#endif
#define N 420000

double* rdm_X(void);
double* rdm_Y(void);
double* rdm_Z(void);

void main(void)
{
   double* Random_number_list_X = rdm_X();
   double* Random_number_list_Y = rdm_Y();
   double* Random_number_list_Z = rdm_Z();
   double X[N+1], Y[N+1], Z[N+1], density = 1, vol = 42.0;
   double sum = 0, sum_x = 0, sum_y = 0, sum_z = 0;
   int i;

   for (i = 0; i <= N; i++) {
      X[i] = 3 * Random_number_list_X[i] + 1;
      Y[i] = 7 * Random_number_list_Y[i] - 3;
      Z[i] = 2 * Random_number_list_Z[i] - 1;
      if ((Z[i]*Z[i]) + (sqrt(X[i]*X[i] + Y[i]*Y[i]) - 3)*(sqrt(X[i]*X[i] + Y[i]*Y[i]) - 3) <= 1) {
         sum += density;
         sum_x += X[i] * density;
         sum_y += Y[i] * density;
         sum_z += Z[i] * density;
      }
   }
   printf("(%.5lf, %.5lf, %.5lf)\n",
            sum_x/sum, sum_y/sum, sum_z/sum);
}

double* rdm_X(void)
{
   double* Random_number_list_X = calloc(N + 1, sizeof(double));
   int i;

   srand(time(NULL));
   for (i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
      Random_number_list_X[i] = (float) rand() / (float) RAND_MAX;
   }
   return Random_number_list_X;
}

double* rdm_Y(void)
{
   double* Random_number_list_Y = calloc(N + 1, sizeof(double));
   int i;
   sleep(1);
   srand(time(NULL));
   for (i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
      Random_number_list_Y[i] = (float) rand() / (float) RAND_MAX;
   }
   return Random_number_list_Y;
}

double* rdm_Z(void)
{
   double* Random_number_list_Z = calloc(N + 1, sizeof(double));
   int i;
   sleep(2);
   srand(time(NULL));
   for (i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
      Random_number_list_Z[i] = (float) rand() / (float) RAND_MAX;
   }
   return Random_number_list_Z;
}
```

Comment: You asked six questions and never accepted an answer. Try to do something about that!

Comment: Any reason why your code is in pastebin and not here?

Comment: I didnt realise I had to, I'll go do it now, cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not the first to point out that you should only call `srand` once, but I'll explain *why*:

**The more often you call `srand` the *less* random the output of `rand` is.**

The `rand` function is a *pseudo*-random number generator. That means that it generates numbers that look random, and have mathematical properties corresponding to randomness, but they aren't actually random. The output of `rand` is actually a fixed, completely deterministic sequence of numbers.

Or, rather, it produces one of a large family of completely deterministic sequences. You select which of these sequences you want by providing a "seed" value using `srand`. When you give `srand` a seed `x`, the next output of `rand` will be the first number of the pseudo-random (but completely deterministic!) sequence identified by the seed `x`. In other words:

```
int foo(int x)
{
   srand(x);
   return rand();
}
```

Will return different values for different inputs, but for a given `x`, will always return the *same* value. Not at all random!

This is actually a useful feature, since if you discover a bug in a program that relies on the output of `rand`, you can reliably reproduce the bug by providing the same seed to `srand` in order to obtain the same sequence from `rand` and so the same behavior from your program.

The reason that you need to call `srand` once is because otherwise your program will always receive the same sequence of numbers from `rand` (the sequence identified by seed `1`). The reason you do *not* want to call `srand` more than once (in most cases) is because you are then repeatedly forcing `rand` back to the beginnings of its sequences rather than letting it give you one of them in its entirety. While any given sequence has properties of randomness, the sequence of sequence-beginnings does not necessarily have this property.

Obviously, it's *especially* bad if you call `srand` repeatedly with the *same* seed, because then you're forcing `rand` back to the beginning of the *same* sequence every time, and so `rand` will always produce the *same* value -- exactly what you don't want.

The reason you commonly see `srand(time(NULL))` is because the time is likely to be different between any two invocations of a given program, which means that every time the program runs it will use a different pseudorandom sequence. But `time` only returns the time to the granularity of seconds, so if you do this repeatedly within a single invocation of a program, as in yours, and less than one second elapses between calls to `srand`, you will be repeatedly re-seeding with the same seed, with ridiculous results, as you have observed.

Bottom Line: Call `srand` exactly once, before your first use of `rand`. Trust that the implementers of the C library wrote a decent pseudo-random number generator, and don't try to "increase randomness" by attempting to compensate for problems that don't exist.

Comment: Actually the "default seed" is 1.

Answer (score 6):

A few points:

1. Don't define `RAND_MAX` yourself.
2. `main` returns an int.
3. Only call `srand` once.
4. Eliminate the extra calls to `srand`, and use one function to initialize your arrays.
5. You defined X, Y, and Z as arrays, but really only used/needed one value each.
6. There seems to be no reason to use dynamic allocation since your arrays sizes are fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The only difference between your three functions is how they call `sleep()`.  Surely you can collapse all three into a single function, and call it three times in a loop?

Comment: It generates the same list of random numbers if I do that

Comment: Then don't reset your random seed each time.

Answer (score 1):

Only call `srand()` **once** per program invocation, typically inside `main()`.

```
int main(void) {
    /* initializations */
    srand(time(NULL));

    /* rest of program, with no more calls to srand() */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Other people already addressed some issues with your program, but do you realize that you are leaking over 10 megabytes of memory every time you run it? free()...

Comment: How so? Im not entirely C competent yet (but I realise a memory leak is bad news!) so any info would be great

Comment: @Jack: every `malloc()` (`calloc()` in your case) **needs** a corresponding `free()` or you have a memory leak. `N * 3 * sizeof (double)` > 10Mbytes. You should `free(Random_number_list_X)` at the end of main.